# I am doing a project for college where we have to create a weblog

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This code is contained in the SQL.php file that holds all the functions for SQL:

function check_login($user_name, $password){

```
#create the PDO object 
/**
 * Used to instanciate the host of the server
 * @var string
 */
    $hostname = 'localhost';
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the username to connect to the server
 * @var string
 */
    $username = 'ODBC';
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the password to connect to the server
 * @var string
 */
    $pass = "";
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the database name
 * @var string
 */
    $db_name = 'bloggie_db';
    try{
        mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8");
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name" , $username, $pass);

        #set PDO error mode to exception 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        #Check to see if the user exists
        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT password, username, firstname, surname FROM users WHERE username = '" . $user_name . "'");  

        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $check_username = $row['username'];
        $check_password = $row['password'];
        $name = $row['firstname'];
        $surname = $row['surname'];

        if ($row){
            if($check_password=$password & $check_username=$user_name){
                header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
                echo 'pass check=  ' . $check_password . '    password=  '. $password . ' firstname= ' . $name . ' surname= ' . $surname;
                return array($name, $surname);
            }else{

                echo "Your details are invalid.";
                return false;
            }
        }else{
            echo "Your account does not exist";
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $e->getTrace();
    }
    $dbh = null;
}
```

When password is printed i get a weird value containing gaves e.g."dapb`" when the value should actually be 6544.

In Login.php i call the sql function:

```
/**
 * Requesting the users username from Bloggie_Welcome.php
 * @var string
 */
$username = $_REQUEST['Email'];

/**
 * Retrieving the users password from Bloggie_Welcome.php
 * @var string
 */
$password = $_REQUEST['Password'];

#Including the path to the validation object
include '../Objects/SQL.php';
#Instanciating the SQL object
$sql = new SQL();
#Calling the sql function check_login
$details = $sql->check_login($username, $password);
session_start();
if(isset($details)){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['firstname'] = $details[0];
    $_SESSION['surname'] = $details[1];
    //header("Location: ../Bloggie_Profile.php");

}
```

i cant seem to understand why when i print the username, password, firstname and surname that all the data is correct except for the password.

Creation of the users table:
    function create_Users(){

```
#create the PDO object 
/**
 * Used to instanciate the host of the server
 * @var string
 */
    $hostname = 'localhost';
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the username to connect to the server
 * @var string
 */
    $username = 'ODBC';
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the password to connect to the server
 * @var string
 */
    $password = "";
            /**
 * Used to instanciate the database name
 * @var string
 */
    $db_name = 'bloggie_db';
    try{

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db_name" , $username, $password);

        echo "<br/>Database connected <br/>";

        #set PDO error mode to exception 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        #create users table
        $sqlU = 'CREATE TABLE users('.
                     'user_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'.
                     'firstname VARCHAR(50),'.
                     'surname VARCHAR(50),'.
                     'username VARCHAR(100),'.
                     'password VARCHAR(255),'.
                     'contact_num VARCHAR(10),'.
                     'email VARCHAR(100),'.
                     'gender VARCHAR(50),'. 
                     'DOB DATE,'.
                     'profile_path VARCHAR(200),'.
                     'bio VARCHAR(255),'.
                     'PRIMARY KEY(user_id))';
        $dbh->exec($sqlU);
        echo "<br/> Users table dropped.";

        $dbh = null;
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo "<br/>" . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
        die(print_r($e->getTrace()));
    }
}
```

PLEASE HELP ME GUYS :(.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a moment to read the [faq#hotwoask] and try to make your question as short as possible. This is not a code writing service. Try to come up with a specific problem and describe what you have done.

Comment: well.. he does ask why is the password printing a strange value.. just kinda buried in all the code there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're doing the most common programming error, just misspelled operator in:

```
if($check_password=$password & $check_username=$user_name){
```

That's why you first assign `$chack_password` to `$password` and do a BINARY AND (`&`) operator on it (not `&&` (AND)) with `$user_name`. `password` now returns a different value.

Just repair if and it should be ok.

Comment: Thank you so so much, I have been struggling for days, what an idiot I am haha, I really appreciate it.